# SERP Image Thumbnails (Gallery) in GOOGLE

Tags: seo, schema.org, rich-snippets, json-ld

n Google SERP we have seen many results of search kind of rich-snippets like Image-gallery or thumbnails. Have red a schema.org how to reach this kind of rich snippet. But didn't find any information about it.

I want to use this kind of rich snippet for a category page.

As we see it's not carousel. It's just images.

The screenshot of example :

[image]

enter image description here

Gentelmen's, any suggestions how can we reach this? Will be appreciated for any information, thank you.